# How to change GTK+ theme?

Tags: 11.10

I am new in ubuntu, i have installed a large set of themes in ubuntu,
i have also installed advanced-system-settings but when i want to change theme in
advaced system settings , themes are not in drop down list?

Answer (score 9):

You can use gnome-tweak-tool to change the GTK+ theme setting. To use gnome-tweak-tool, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Note that installing gnome-tweak-tool also installs gnome-shell.

Search for `gnome-tweak-tool` or `Advanced Settings` (as it is named) in the Unity dash and open the tool.

Move to 'Theme' option on the left sidebar. You can now change the GTK+ theme by changing the options in the dropdown list. Check the image for clarification.

[image]