# How do I change the theme and window border color?

Tags: themes, colors

Is it possible to customise the colours for the desktop theme and window appearance in Pangolin 12.04 as it was possible in Narwhal?
I only see four default choices in the display adjustment selection.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you provide more details what you wanted to change? Are you referring to the selection colors? or the colors of the window border (In Ambiance, it is a dark color) itself? In the first case, [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/63126/61218) can be useful for you.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe. Because other question asks changing theme while this asks customizing current theme

Comment: @Anwar That makes sense. I've voted to reopen this. (While [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93278/how-to-change-gtk-theme) are related I can see how they're not the same and how they don't cover what's being asked here.) You might also want to post on meta; oftentimes, in this sort of situation, a closed question won't get much attention otherwise. (Though I see you've brought this up in chat, which can sometimes be sufficient.)

Answer (score 6):

You said,

> Is it possible to customise the colours for the desktop theme and window appearance in Pangolin 12.04 as it was possible in Narwhal?

I assume, you are referring to the customization window in the theme in Natty Narwhal and previous distributions. Since, Gnome 3 is released, those easy customization options are removed default.

But, the good news is, the corresponding keys in `gconf` and hence `dconf` is available still now. So, you can change those keys using `dconf-editor` (dconf-editor or gsettings should be used instead of gconf, since settings are migrating to dconf).

I've tested in Narwhal and found the corresponding keys, the path is  `/org/gnome/desktop/interface` and

the keys are as follows:

1. `bg_color` - It refers to the window color. This corresponds to left color selection in *Windows* row  i.e 1st row in Narwhal.
2. `fg_color` - This controls the text colors in windows, menus, title bars etc. This is the right side color selection in *Windows* row (It does not change the text color in input boxes, nautilus folder pane etc, text in editors etc).
3. `base_color` - This controls the background colors in input boxes, nautilus folder pane, editor's background, search bar, address bar in browsers etc. Corresponds to the left color selection in *Input boxes* row in Narwhal.
4. `text_color` - This controls the text colors (foreground colors) in the above settings, such as input boxes, nautilus folder pane, editor's text, search bar, address bar's text etc. Corresponds to the right color selection box in *Input boxes* row in Narwhal.
5. `selected_bg_color` - This controls the background color i,e the color of any selections, when you select with your mouse etc. Corresponds to the *Selected Items* row's left-most settings in Narwhal.
6. `selected_fg_color` - This controls the **text colors withing selection**. Corresponds to the *Selected Items* row's right settings.
7. `tooltip_bg_color` - This I think self-explanatory. It controls the background colors of a tooltip. Corresponds to the  *Tooltips* row's first settings.
8. `tooltip_fg_color` - This controls the tool tip text color. Corresponds to the right settings in *Tooltips* row in Narwhal

   [image: image of appearance window]

#### How to set those colors:

You can easily set those colors in dconf-editor. Install it via  terminal with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

or via Software Center [image: Install via the software center]

Now, Open dconf-editor by typing the name in dash. To do so, Press <kbd>Super</kbd> and type *dconf-editor* and Click on the icon.

Go to the path `org` -> `gnome` -> `desktop` -> `interface` and select `gtk-color-scheme` and input value there. **Don't forget** to put a `;` after each key-value pair. For example, If you want to change the window color(bg_color) and window text color(fg_color) with some values, the line should be like this:

```
bg_color:#2f568f;fg_color:#000000;
```

#### Generate color value:

To generate color value, you can use the Appearance Window in System Settings. To bring it. Right Click on Desktop -> Choose *Change Desktop Background* and in the Window, click the little color box below the big Monitor image. There you can see a *custom* color box. click there.

Alternatively, you can use `agave` color generator. It is a very convenient and tiny tool to generate color value. Install it with terminal using the commmand:

```
sudo apt-get install agave
```

or using Software center [image: Install via the software center]

Type agave in the dash to open it after pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>

#### Changing window border color:

Changing window border's color of default *Ambiance* and *Radiance* themes aren't supported. Because, those themes use images as window borders. If you really want to have the ability to change the window border, I suggest you to use old colorable window borders such as *Crux*, *Esco*, *Human* etc.

Some are included in the default Ubuntu installation. You can use those by using Ubuntu-tweak.

- [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75454/61218)

After installation, open it by Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> and typing "Ubuntu tweak" in the dash. Then go to *Tweaks* -> *Themes* and then change *Window Theme*.