# Selection and toggles are not highlighted in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, themes, gtk

I recently updated to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Since update, settings in ubuntu doesn't have proper selection highlighted.

[image: See the screen shot, which selection is selected is not highlighted]

Also menu items appears to be cramped

[image: look at File, Edit, etc]

Output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme` is `'Arc'`.

Comment: What is the output of the following command in Terminal: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme`?

Comment: I tried running `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme`, its shows only `'Arc'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the GTK+ theme you're currently using (Arc in your case) is broken (or unavailable) somehow.

Install *(GNOME) Tweaks* by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

and use it to change your GTK+ theme (try the default ones: Ambiance and Radiance). See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93278/how-to-change-gtk-theme) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 I had the same issue. I fixed it with the following:

```
sudo apt purge arc-theme
sudo apt install arc-theme
```

Note: be aware that this will completely remove arc-them including any customizations.