# How to Change GTK2/GTK3 Themes in Ubuntu 18.04+

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

The answer in [How to change GTK+ theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93278/how-to-change-gtk-theme) is not working for me anymore:

It has never been a problem to me before, but now, within Ubuntu 18.04, it is not working for me any more.

Basically, I'm following,
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-change-ubuntu-theme/

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
gnome-tweaks &
```

[image]

However, flipping through the Themes in the "Applications" drop down has no effects at all. So,

- How to Change GTK Themes in Ubuntu? (It is GTK2 Theme that I'm especially interested in, and having difficulties with)
- And ultimately, how to change GTK Theme on command line?

PS,

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

This is a minimum installation machine started from net-install, so I need to install packages before using them.

PPS

I saw the following message when starting `gnome-tweaks`, might that be the culprit? How to fix it if so?

```
WARNING : Shell not installed or running
```

Comment: Are you sure you have gnome3 as Desktop? `env | grep -i desktop
`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not, :-) -- I'm using fluxbox (at home under Ubuntu and MS Windows as Desktop at work for my xapps in my Windows hosted VM), and need to pick GTK themes (both versions) for my GTK based applications, which I was able to do previously. @user966203